# c# winforms how to get the highest ColumnIndex

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I need to get the the highest ColumnIndex among SelectedCells in a DataGridView.

int i = theHighestColumnIndexAmongSelectedCells.

Or

```
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dgv.SelectedCells)  
if cell.ColumnIndex is theHighest  
int i = cell.ColumnIndex.
```

How might I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way it to use the LINQ [Max()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534962.aspx) function:

```
int max = dgv.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Max(c => c.ColumnIndex);
```